# Equivalent ways to study perturbed abstract Cauchy problem

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, operator-theory

I am considering the following abstract Cauchy problem on Banach space $X$:
\begin{cases}
u'(t)=Au(t)+\big(f(t)+Bu(t)\big),&t\in[0,T],\\
u(0)=x_0,
\end{cases}
Suppose $A$ generates a $C_0$ semi-group $S(t)$ on $X$, then under certain assumptions, we can study the wellposeness of the following integral equation for the original Cauchy problem:
\begin{equation}
u(t)=S(t)x_0+\int_0^t S(t-s)\big(f(s)+Bu(s)\big)\, ds.\tag{1}\label{eq:noper}
\end{equation}

However, we can also view $A+B$ as a perturbation of $A$, hence suppose $A+B$ also generates a $C_0$ semi-group $T(t)$ on $X$, then we can also study
\begin{equation}
u(t)=T(t)x_0+\int_0^t T(t-s)f(s)\, ds.\tag{2}\label{eq:per}
\end{equation}

Intuitively, I think the wellposedness of \eqref{eq:noper} and \eqref{eq:per} should be equivalent since they come from two different ways to interpret the same Cauchy problem (at least with good assumptions for $x_0$ and $B$). But is there any reference with rigorous arguments you can point out?

For your information, the specific problem I am considering is $A$ be an elliptic  2nd order operator and $B$ be a first order operator.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately this is not so simple/immediate and does depend on the type of equation and perturbation.

I suggest that before anything else you have a look at the Engel-Nagel book, more precisely at Chapter 3 (such as at their Theorem 3.14). They also include discussions of some specific types of equations, although I don't remind elliptic.

Comment: So may I confirm that what you mean is that it's possible that a mild solution to equation (2) (wrt $T(t)$) is NOT a mild solution to equation (1) (wrt $S(t)$), and conversely neither. But are they both solutions to the original problem?

Comment: I have skimmed through the reference you mentioned. It seems that $S(t)$ and $T(t)$ are only related under some assumptions of $B$ (by the variation of parameters formula). I am just confused why they are both associated with the original Cauchy problem, but the well-posed of the two equations are not equivalant.

Comment: @John ZHANG Sorry, I was out of town. I agree with you, but these is the type of results that are available. On the other hand, they don't really say that the problems are equivalent, right? :) Maybe many of them (that is, under various types of assumptions) should indeed be equivalent. The truth is that it is more common that each problem is studied by itself not suprisingly in connection with PDE's. So, I regret that I cannot be more detailed.